# "Engineered" is a difficult word to translate

Tags: translation

How would you translate "Engineered" into Japanese by the following examples?

1. Engineered chemistry ; engineered arts
2. Clinical transplantation of a tissue-engineered airway
3. Engineered for freedom
4. Engineered explosives
5. Hardware and software engineered to work together

I feel this word can have multiple meanings when it is translated into Japanese.

For 1 and 4 I suppose the word engineered more related to meaning as in "改造".

For 2 I figure the word is closer to ”tissueを介した”.

For 3 and 5 the word could mean "...のためにデザイン（構築）した"

Does anyone have a different thought?

Comment: I don't think the English terms you ask for are clear to everyone (especially non-native speakers). "Engineered for freedom" looks like a copy for an ad campaign (the translation would probably be different depending on the object), but what "engineered arts" mean? I have no clue. Either requires more context.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about #1 and 3, it depends on the context, but 設計 or 調整 may work. 誂えられた might be.

2: issue engineering is 組織工学 but since followed by airway, it becomes 人工器官.

4: 仕込まれた爆弾 is descriptive. 爆弾トラップ or ブービートラップ may to be used..

5: is 開発された in general.
デザイン is not used as IT term because it sounds somehow about fashons.
IT terms for engineering are 開発する、 設計する、実装する、プログラムする、組み込む .